# find length of longest line in all text files in a directory

Tags: awk

I know how to get length of the longest line in a text file with `awk`

```
awk ' { if ( length > L ) { L=length} }END{ print L}' file.txt
```

but how can I get the length of the longest line of all files in a directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to concatenate all the files and pipe the result to your script:

```
cat ./* | awk '{ if ( length > L ) { L=length} }END{ print L}'
```

You can also pass directly several files to awk:

```
awk '{ if ( length > L ) { L=length} }END{ print L}' ./*
```

Of course, there can be some warnings if files are in fact directories but it should be harmless. You may have bigger problems with binary files because they don't have a concept of *line*. So, in order to be more specific, you can do something like

```
 awk '{ if ( length > L ) { L=length} }END{ print L}' ./*.txt
```

to match only the `.txt` files in the current directory.

And, as @G-Man stated in his comment, `*` won't match hidden files (starting with a dot). If you want those, use `* .*`.

Comment: Or, arguably, `cat * .* | ...`. Or eliminate the [useless use of cat](http://superuser.com/questions/323060/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-useless-use-of-cat) and say `awk '...' * .*`.

Comment: @G-Man Indeed. I was editing my answer about that when you commented. :-) I said _most straightforward_ because concatenating the files with _cat_ is what seemed simpler at first.

Comment: use this modification to also output the content of the longest line:
`awk '{ if ( length > L ) { L=length ;s=$0 } }END{ print L,"\""s"\"" }' **/*.txt`

Answer (score 6):

If you want the max length per file, with GNU awk:

```
find . -type f -exec awk -v l=0 '
   length>l {l=length} ENDFILE{print FILENAME ":", l; l=0}' {} +
```

Or the one max length in all the files:

```
find . -type f -size +1c -exec cat {} + |
  awk -v l=0 'length>l {l=length}; END{print l}'
```

That assumes the files end in newline characters. If one file doesn't end in a newline character, then its last non-delimited line will be merged with the first line of the next file and possibly void your result.

`-size +1c` is an optimisation as text files that are empty or contain only one character have respectively 0 line and 1 empty line, so won't have the longest line.

Comment: They're text files, so they do end in newline characters (unless empty).

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `wc`:

```
cat *.txt|wc -L
```

`-L` prints the length of the longest line.

Comment: GNU's `-L` option is horrible, it counts single tabs as being 8 bytes each

Answer (score 0):

Also with GNU wc (coreutils 8.4), it can handle multiple files

```
wc -L *.txt
```

- lists the length of each individual file
- as well as provide the longest length of all files

Comment: This is essentially what [this other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152746/33055) mentioning `wc -L` does, but your solution has the disadvantage that you have to wade through the max-length of all the other files first. Is there any advantage in that?